# padrino with sequel posting to multiple models with one form

Tags: ruby, sequel, padrino

I am trying to post and save the form, which contains data for 2 models, they are connected with associations. But it fails on

```
Sequel::MassAssignmentRestriction
```

that the method for column from associated table does not exists. I understand the error and find the answer for rails. Which is to use

```
accepts_nested_attributes
```

but I am using Padrino, not rails. So I try nested_parameters but it didn't work and documentation tells just

```
The nested_attributes call defines a single method, association_attributes=, (e.g. albums_attributes=). So if you have an Artist instance:
```

which I understand that it is not what I need, for storing all with

```
@article = Article.new(params[:article])
```

and associated tables.

Please, do You know how to use it with Padrino and what is right way

Thanks

Comment: You need to allow Sequel to mass assign values on a model: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/mass_assignment_rdoc.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! It work! Thank You, I didn't connect it in my mind

Comment: Great! Sequel is a very powerful tool and it usually does everything you wioll ever need.

Comment: Yes it is, but for me as a beginner is sometimes hard, because its a lots of docs and I start to implement something which is perfectly solved already. But everyday I learn a lots of new things.